# Erase all lines except for the current one

Tags: key-bindings

Does anyone one know of a short key sequence that would do the equivalent of `:1,-d:+,$d`? Yes, I know you can define a function, macro, and that would be nice. But, maybe a bit more elegant if you could hit some predefined keys, letters, controls, and get the same result.

Comment: not exactly short... `yyggdG"0P` on the line you want to preserve.. however that leaves a extra empty line.. you could also do `:1,-d | +,$d` for single command line execution instead of two

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this will do:

```
:v/\%#/d
```

That should deal with corner cases like the line you want to keep being the
first line in the buffer, etc.

Or perhaps `:move` the current line to the beginning of the buffer and delete the rest:

```
:m0|+,$d
```

or:

```
YggPjdG
```

To repeat later, either map it to a key, or maybe grab it from your history with `:v<up>` for example.

*References:*
`:help :v`
`:help /\%#`

Comment: Some more: `:.w!|e!` and `YggVGp`